# Can't install discount with pip: error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pip, osx-mavericks

I am running into many problems when trying to install the `discount` package on osx 10.9 Mavericks. I'm working with the django framework.

My steps are (while having a virtualenv activated):

```
pip install discount
```

Then I get:

```
.
.
.

1 error generated.

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /Users/KaeserMic/Sites/2013/Duotones/naturkostbar/env/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/KaeserMic/Sites/2013/Duotones/naturkostbar/env/build/discount/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/4b/smwv2y_s32z044brp6t__ssh0000gp/T/pip-65i7x3-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /Users/KaeserMic/Sites/2013/Duotones/naturkostbar/env/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /Users/KaeserMic/Sites/2013/Duotones/naturkostbar/env/build/discount
Storing complete log in /Users/KaeserMic/.pip/pip.log
```

Here is the complete log:

https://gist.github.com/MichaelKaeser/7302829

Things I did:

- updating python
- updating pip
- updating virtualenv
- updating homebrew

Any ideas how to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `cc` is a C compiler. Do you have a C compiler installed?

Comment: (edited complete log link, btw) Does this compiler not come with the xcode command line tools? If not, what should I install?

Comment: Hmm, based on your log it seems like it is able to find the C compiler. So I'm not sure anymore! The error is coming because `unterminated conditional directive`... You appear to also be missing some dependencies... `markdown requires either strcasecmp() or stricmp()`. Try googling those things? Sorry I can't help further :-) Those are on lines 255 and 102 of your log file, btw.

Comment: I updated recently to Mavericks, are there other things I may should install/update to work with python and pip..?

Comment: Post the full error message, I've had similar, and I have a feeling there is an error before the `cc` error that you ended up not sharing :)

Comment: @MichaelKaeser if one of the answers worked for you, be sure to mark it so others with the same problem can figure out how to fix it :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try:

`sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install discount`

This seems to be an issue with LLVM in XCode 5.1 as mentioned here: [Can't install mysql gem on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312583/cant-install-mysql-gem-on-os-x)

Comment: Note to any copy/paster's that the `pip install` command for the OP's package is on the end of that command. You might have to edit if you got this error while installing something else.

Comment: It helped me installing jellyfish on Mac OS X 10.9. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

If you enter `gcc` or `cc` in the terminal, will it output an error? Do you have Xcode installed?

```
xcode-select....
```

If so, Mac Os Mavericks should alert you to install Xcode Command Line Tools.

Comment: Yes it ouutputs both an error: `clang: error: no input files`. But I do have Xcode installed, version 5.0.1

Comment: That error is normal because there's no input file. `cc` is installed on your mac by default I guess. Anyway, just google for `Xcode Command Line Tools 10.9` and install them.

Comment: Try this: `ln -s  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers/X11 /usr/local/include/X11`

Comment: I created the link to X11 like you explained, but it doesn't change anything. What's the link supposed to achieve?

Comment: It's creating a symbolic link for X11, some people worked with them. Anyway, these are the main problems. The last thing I could think of is to run `xcode-select --install` in the terminal, in case you already installed the tools, it shouldn't download. Give it a shot anyway. I had the same issue, and it worked after installing the xcode command line tools.

Comment: Tried it, but an alert window pops up with: `Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server.` Already did that 12 hours ago...

Comment: I add the same error on Mavericks. Although Xcode was installed, I still needed to run the xcode-select command as explained in the answer to make it work.    `xcode-select --install`