# Can't install mysql gem on OS X

Tags: mysql, ruby, macos, rubygems, clang

I'm doing a

> sudo gem install mysql

on OS X to install the mysql gem. This fails with the following output:

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>
> ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
>
> ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
>
> checking for mysql_ssl_set()... yes
>
> checking for rb_str_set_len()... yes
>
> checking for rb_thread_start_timer()... no
>
> checking for mysql.h... yes
>
> creating Makefile
>
> make "DESTDIR=" clean
>
> make "DESTDIR="
>
> compiling mysql.c
>
> linking shared-object mysql/mysql_api.bundle
>
> clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-> argument-hard-error-in-future]
>
> clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
>
> make: *** [mysql_api.bundle] Error 1
>
> make failed, exit code 2
>
> Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1 for inspection.
>
> Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/mysql-2.9.1/gem_make.out

Any idea what could be causing this? I have mysql installed with homebrew if that makes a difference.

Comment: I think you want to install mysql**2** gem, don't you? `gem install mysql2`

Comment: This is caused by Apple Clang 5.1 (which was just released today). It is affecting many people so hopefully a fix/workaround will be available soon.

Comment: @Rafa Trying to install mysql2 runs into exactly the same error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply\_definedsuppress'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[From Apple's Xcode/Clang release notes:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction/Introduction.html)

> The Apple LLVM compiler in Xcode 5.1 treats unrecognized command-line options as errors. This issue has been seen when building both Python native extensions and Ruby Gems, where some invalid compiler options are currently specified.
>   Projects using invalid compiler options will need to be changed to remove those options. To help ?ease that transition, the compiler will temporarily accept an option to downgrade the error to a warning:
>
> `-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future`
>
> `ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install GemName`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Saved me when I was setting up a newly installed Mavericks and needed the Postgres python driver. Thanks!

Comment: YES! Was having trouble with `pip install psutil` errors and this fixes it in my `virtualenv` (`venv`): `ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future ./venv/bin/pip install psutil`

Comment: This helped me with `pip install`

Answer (score 7):

Seems to be an issue with Apple's rbconfig.rb:

```
$ grep -n DLDFLAGS /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/rbconfig.rb
82:  CONFIG["LIBRUBY_DLDFLAGS"] = "-undefineddynamic_lookup -multiply_definedsuppress -install_name $(libdir)/$(LIBRUBY_SO) -current_version $(MAJOR).$(MINOR).$(TEENY) -compatibility_version $(ruby_version)  $(XLDFLAGS)"
84:  CONFIG["EXTDLDFLAGS"] = ""
125:  CONFIG["DLDFLAGS"] = "-undefineddynamic_lookup -multiply_definedsuppress"
```

Removing the `-multiply_definedsuppress` should allow it to install.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to Xcode 5.1 - its already reported as a bug to Ruby.

https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9624

There is some more additional discussion here:
[Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are correct. The easiest fix though is to rebuild ruby on your machine. Gem extensions use the ruby build configuration when it was itself built and if you built your ruby before the Xcode 5.1, its build configuration contains the offending flags.

This should fix it for all of the many affected gems.