# Neither Pillow nor PIL could be imported: No module named Image

Tags: django, heroku, python-imaging-library

I am trying to use PIL/Pillow in my django app, running in virtualenv, for eventual deployment to Heroku.

Steps I have done:

- started virtualenv (source venv/bin/activate)
- pip install pillow

Output:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-    error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

otherwise, there were a lot of copied files:
   e.g. `copying PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/PIL`

However, running python manage.py runserver fails with the error message in the title. Tried pip install pil and does not work. Any inkling on how to fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: oh found the answer

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install pillow
```

the unused arguments was preventing further install of pillow. the above tells it to not treat the unused argument as an error.

Found at (To Read more): [Can't install mysql gem on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312583/cant-install-mysql-gem-on-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with virtualenv and Django, following command fixed that:

```
easy_install PIL
```