# Trouble Installing Pillow: Why Am I Receiving Errors?

Tags: python, macos, pip, python-imaging-library

I'm attempting to install pillow via pip (i.e. `sudo pip install pillow`) but without much success.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Here are the errors I receive:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-l7hSHg-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/pillow
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [clang error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' (python package installation failure)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/clang-error-unknown-argument-mno-fused-madd-python-package-installation-fa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install pillow
```

you will see a lot of warnings but it worked for me.

the unused arguments was preventing further install of pillow. the above tells it to not treat the unused argument as an error.

Source: [a/22774631/1142814](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22774631/1142814)

EDIT: I link here the official issue you linked in your comment, maybe it can be helpful for someone else:  https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/issues/527

Comment: Thank you sir. I found [this](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/issues/527) helpful as well.