# gem mysql2 ERROR

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just upgraded my mac to OS X 10.9.8.

I got some solution when I google this problem.
(Ex : install Xcode , install mysql..ect)

But that still can't fix this problem.

Try to install gem:
    ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
-----
Using mysql_config at /usr/local/bin/mysql_config
-----
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
-----
Setting rpath to /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.17_1/lib
-----
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling client.c
compiling infile.c
compiling mysql2_ext.c
compiling result.c
linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [mysql2.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.15 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/mysql2-0.3.15/gem_make.out
```

The solution is `sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install mysql2`.

If anyone got same problem,you can try `ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install gem_name`.

Comment: http://bruteforce.gr/bypassing-clang-error-unknown-argument.html ?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312583/cant-install-mysql-gem-on-os-x